# Create ripple effect in a angular js directive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have created an angular directive.It is basically a button.Upon clicking this button it should change it's background color in a ripple pattern.The ripple has to start from the point where the user has clicked on the button.
My directive

```js
angular.module("myApp",[])
  .directive('myButton', function(){
    return{
      restrict:'E',
      templateUrl:'button.html',
      link:function(scope,element,attrs){
        element.bind('click', function(e){
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

button.html

```html
<div id="button">My Button</div>
```

I want do this by manipulating the DOM and using page cordinates in an angular way.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way is to use buttons from Angular Material, it's pretty easy
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/button

Comment: No Sir i don't want to use Angular Material and what i'm trying to do here is  change the background of my button(directive) in a ripple effect way permanently and not a momentary ripple effect as shown in the Angular-material.I have seen it being done using pure javascript by performing dom-manipulation and css transform property but i want to implement it in a angular way using a directive.